why would grecaptcha.ready(function()) suddenly be returning false?
I have been pulling my hair out trying to solve the riddle of why our booking page just stopped working. One issue was a code issue that I fixed. then there was a credit card issue with Google Maps account which may or may not be related to this. And now I have found that grecaptcha.ready(function() in this code is jumping down to "return false:" but I cannot figure out why.
        var bookform = jQuery(this);
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            grecaptcha.execute(url_paths.recaptcha_site_key, {action: 'booking'}).then(function(token) {
                bookform.find( ".g-recaptcha-response" ).val( token );

                jQuery("#bookingbuttonvrp").hide();
                jQuery("#vrploadinggif").show();
                jQuery("span.vrpmsg").remove();
                jQuery(".badfields").removeClass("badfields");
                jQuery("#comments").val(jQuery("#comments").val());
                jQuery.post(url_paths.site_url + "/?vrpjax=1&act=processbooking", bookform.serialize(), function(data){

                    console.log(data);

                    var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    if (typeof(obj.Error) !== 'undefined' && obj.Error.length != 0) {
                        jQuery("#bookingbuttonvrp").show();
                        jQuery("#vrploadinggif").hide();
                        alert(obj.Error);
                    } else if (obj.Bad.length != 0){
                        jQuery("#bookingbuttonvrp").show();
                        jQuery("#vrploadinggif").hide();
                        jQuery.each(obj.Bad,function(k,v){
                            jQuery("#" + k + "tr td:last").append('<span class="vrpmsg alert alert-error">' + v + '</span>');
                            var oldcolor=jQuery("#" + k + "tr").css("color");
                            jQuery("#" + k + "tr").addClass("badfields");
                            jQuery("#" + k).change(function(){
                                jQuery("#" + k + "tr").removeClass("badfields");
                                jQuery("#" + k + "tr td span.vrpmsg").remove();
                            });
                        });
                        jQuery("html, body").animate({
                            scrollTop: 0
                        }, "slow",function(){});
                        alert(Object.values(obj.Bad).join("\n"));

                    } else {
                        window.location=jQuery("#vrpbookform").attr("action");
                    }

                });
            });
        });
        return false;
    });

How in the world do I troubleshoot this and get the booking page to work again?
Checked to see that the site key is correct. I corrected a Google billing issue that was being used for maps (unsure if it affected this). I reset and reinstalled Google Site Kit. And I don't know what else to do. (I am completely green at JavaScript coding).
